# line stream manipulation (adding space bw desired digits) using bash

Tags: bash

have below lines:

```
123.100.011
123.100.100
```

I would like to add spaces bw. digits and produce the following output in each line.

```
123 100 011
123 100 100
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to add your efforts which you have tried to solve your problem in your post too.

Answer (score 1):

might be easier with `tr`

```
$ tr . ' ' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment in case `.` is NOT there in input and wants to add space into digits then following may help.

```
echo "123100011" | awk '{while($0){val=val?val OFS substr($0,1,3):substr($0,1,3);$0=substr($0,4)};print val;val=""}'
```

---

---

Try using `sed` or `awk` for this.

```
sed 's/\./ /g' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{gsub(/\./," ");print}' Input_file
```

Comment: what about the case when plurality of different stream configs appear in the file, like 123.100.011
123100100
123-100-100

Comment: @Luisy, sorry I didn't get, could you please elaborate more on this request?

Comment: what about is the "." is missed in some of the stream lines? So the input file will have 123.100.011 config,...but it may also have 123100011. I still would like to add "space" every 3 digits for each of the stream lines. Having try >> tr '^[1-2][0-9][0-9]\{3}$'  '  ' < MyFile.txt > NewFIle.txt ….but it doesn't work as desired.

Comment: @Luisy, please check EDIT solution too now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably superfluous all-bash one-liner:

```
while IFS=. read a b c; do echo "$a $b $c";done < file.txt
```

or for arbitrary ragged records,

```
while IFS=. read -a line; do echo "${line[@]}";done < file.txt
```

All the other answers are better on files of any size unless you need to process each line as you have them...in which case this might come in handy. ;)